# Creating a list of objects in Java

Tags: java

So I was thinking of creating a list of objects like this

```
ArrayList<Obj> lst = new ArrayList<Obj>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Obj elem = new Obj();
  lst.add(elem);
}
```

Is this legal or do I have to worry about Object 1 getting trashed when the elem reference starts pointing to Object 2?  If it's illegal, how might I do it otherwise?  Is there a way to automatically generate ten different reference names?

Comment: No you only have to worry about Object 1 getting trashed when there are no references left to the lst structure. The elem reference is "fresh" each time.

Comment: Your two lines inside the loop can also be written as `lst.add(new Obj());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garbage Collector will remove objects only when there are no references pointing to it. 
In your case, your list will be pointing to 10 distinct **Object** objects and they are safe until you lose reference to **lst** Object.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly legal. Your `ArrayList` will contain a reference to the object you just created, so it will not be GCed.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is perfectly valid. You will end up with a list of ten distinct objects.